# Rundeck ACL's work for one AD group but not another

Tags: rundeck

So I have my ACL's set up identical in 2 groups.  They're working well for one group, but I tried to set up the other identical but they aren't working.  I have them in 2 separate ACL Policies at both in Cog / Access Control and Project / Project Settings / Access Control.  I have cut and pasted all but the group name in each case so I would expect them to work the same.  The groups live in Active Directory in a different subfolder of my roleBaseDn in my jaas-multiauth.conf file.  Here is one of the Cog / Access Control Level policies:

```
description: Admin project level access control
context:
  project: '.*' # all projects
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: job
      allow: [create] # allow create jobs
    - equals:
        kind: node
      allow: [read,create,update,refresh] # allow refresh node sources
    - equals:
        kind: event
      allow: [read,create] # allow read/create events
  adhoc:
    - allow: [read,run,runAs,kill,killAs] # allow running/killing adhoc jobs
  job:
    - allow: [create,read,update,delete,run,runAs,kill,killAs] # allow create/read/write/delete/run/kill of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: [read,run] # allow read/run for nodes
by:
  group: Group-Zero

---

description:  All jobs access control
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: project
      allow: [create] # allow create of projects
    - equals:
        kind: system
      allow: [read,enable_executions,disable_executions,admin] # allow read of system info, enable/disable all executions
    - equals:
        kind: system_acl
      allow: [read,create,update,delete,admin] # allow modifying system ACL files
    - equals:
        kind: user
      allow: [admin] # allow modify user profiles
  project:
    - match:
        name: '.*'
      allow: [read,import,export,configure,delete,promote,admin] # allow full access of all projects or use 'admin'
  project_acl:
    - match:
        name: '.*'
      allow: [read,create,update,delete,admin] # allow modifying project-specific ACL files
  storage:
    - allow: [read,create,update,delete] # allow access for /ssh-key/* storage content

by:
  group: Group-One
```

The other is identical but different AD group.  Here's the Project Level Settings, both in one:

```
description: User project level access control. Applies to resources within a specific project.
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: job
      allow: [read,run,refresh] # allow create jobs
    - equals:
        kind: node
      allow: [read] # allow read node sources
    - equals:
        kind: event
      allow: [read] # allow read events
  adhoc:
    - allow: [read] # allow read adhoc jobs
  job:
    - allow: [read,run] # allow read/run of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: [read] # allow read/run for nodes
by:
  group: Group-One

---
description: User project level access control. Applies to resources within a specific project.
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: job
      allow: [read,run,refresh] # allow create jobs
    - equals:
        kind: node
      allow: [read] # allow read node sources
    - equals:
        kind: event
      allow: [read] # allow read events
  adhoc:
    - allow: [read] # allow read adhoc jobs
  job:
    - allow: [read,run] # allow read/run of all jobs
  node:
    - allow: [read] # allow read/run for nodes
by:
  group: Group-Two
```

Seems to me that I don't need the second group for the Project level ACL Policy since I don't want those users messing with the project settings, but just need to get them access ASAP.  Figured I can trim down their privs once I get this working.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must define your ACL with this structure (check the "context" block before "for:"). You don't have these lines defined in the second ACL.

```yml
    description: Allow groups to list projects
    context:
      application: 'rundeck'
    for:
      project:
      - allow: read
        match:
          name: '.*'
    by:
      group: [group-two]

    ---

    description: Global run permissions
    context:
      project: '.*'
    for:
      resource:
      - equals:
          kind: 'node'
        allow: [read,refresh]
      job:
      - allow: [read, run]
        match:
          name: '.*'
      node:
      - allow: [read, run, refresh]
        match:
          nodename: '.*'
      resource:
      - allow: read
        equals:
          kind: event
    by:
      group: [group-two]
```

You have a good example [here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authorization.html#example).

Also, make sure that another ACL isn't overriden the rules of your first one.

If you need some examples (under Rundeck 3.1) you can check the /etc/rundeck directory and see the ".aclpolicy_template" files.

Comment: Are you saying you can only have one ACL Policy?  I have multiples.

Comment: If you need the same rules for two groups, yes, you can use one ACL for those groups. (Check the "group" line on each context).

Comment: I don't want the same rules for each group.  I'd rather they be different rules.  I was just trying to get a second group to work but it won't.  I wanted one group to be admin and another to have jobs access, even specific jobs.  I had what I thought would work, but when folks from those groups log on, they get on but it shows they have access to 0 projects.

Comment: Now I see, well, I see that on the "users" ACL you don't define the context like the first one. Check carefully the structure (I'll change my answer ASAP :-) ).

Comment: Ahhh, so it's the project level settings that are messed up.  Let me try fixing that, thanks!

Comment: Something I'm not getting is when I enter policy via the Project Settings and when via Cog / Access Control?  Do I need both policies?  Sorry, I've read through this more than once and it just rattles around in my head, lol...

Comment: Make sure that you're login as Admin profile to access to ACLs (Gear Icon -> Access Control).

Comment: So when I add context to a Project ACL Policy, I get Context section should not be specified, it is already set to: {project=MyProjectName]

I see that at the top it says Project:  MyProjectName
since this is a Project ACL Policy rather than System ACL Policy.

Comment: Note that in the cog / access control, there are 3 local policies now with 2 polocies inside of each one.  Then there is one Stored ACL Policy with 2 policies in it.  I assume the local called "admin" is for the local admin user.  So are the local policies for local users and the stored for Active Directory users in my case?

Comment: Right, "admin" is the default policy for the admin user, the rest is your "custom" ACLs. As advice: backup all data  before changes, the ACL are stored at: /etc/rundeck/ (.aclpolicy files)

Comment: So when I set an ACL using Project Settings, is it just the same as setting one via Cog / Access Control and specifying that specific project as context?

Comment: Not the same, in Project Settings you only need one context: the rundeck context (and of course is per project), my example is for "cog -> access control" :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it looks like my ACL's weren't the issue.  My users were trying to get in with Internet Explorer.  Apparently there are some settings in IE that don't agree with Rundeck.  The login would work but it would just spin trying to load projects.  I had one of them click the cog and they had all kinds of accesses.  Once they went to it with Edge or Firefox, the project loaded right away and were able to do whatever they needed to.  Thanks for all the time educating me on ACL's, they actually make some sense now!

Comment: Good news then! Keep away from Internet Explorer ;)